# How to create Android Database application?

Tags: android, sqlite

I am new to Databases and do not know if this would be the best way to do what I want to achieve. I want to create a custom list of restaurants around me, then search them, and sort them on ranking, title, or location.

Would I need to create a database for this? I technically could use a text file and Arrays but I feel like this is very inefficient. I would need a Node to contain the following data: Name of Establishment, Address, Phone Number, Ranking (Based of Our Ranking System).

How should I go about doing this?

Comment: If the data needs toe be searched at all, just use SQLite and treat data like data. Don't worry about "inefficiency", worry about getting it done with enough flexibility to expand *into the immediate future*. If you are having questions about the scheme, I'd suggest an SQL book/tutorial.

Comment: @pst I do not want to create this database at run time, which is what all the tutorials i have found are doing. I want them to be pulled offline so I can update and manage this database. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: That's fine. Create the SQLite database on a PC (or wherever). Copy the database to the device: SQLite is awesome this way. Additionally, the database can be exported to SQL commands, or CSV etc, and then trivially loaded (the first time). Although it does sound like you want to employ some sort of (automatic) synchronization solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you definitely want to use a database. If you use a database local to the phone, you need to use an SQLite database. [Here](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html) is a good place to start.

If you want a database that is preloaded in the phone, put it in your assets folder. Here is an example of a database helper class with the database packaged with the phone:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Vector;


import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

private static final String TAG = "DataBaseHelper";

//The Androids default system path of your application database.
private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/yourpackage/databases/";

private static String DB_NAME = "DatabaseName";

public SQLiteDatabase myDataBase; 

private final Context myContext;


    /**
     * Constructor
     * Takes and keeps a reference of the passed context in order to access to the application assets and resources.
     * @param context
     */
    public DataBaseHelper(Context context) {

        super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
        this.myContext = context;
    }   

  /**
     * Creates a empty database on the system and rewrites it with your own database.
     * */
    public void createDataBase() throws IOException{

        boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();

        if(dbExist){
            //do nothing - database already exist
        }else{

            //By calling this method and empty database will be created into the default system path
               //of your application so we are gonna be able to overwrite that database with our database.
            this.getWritableDatabase();

            try {

                copyDataBase();

            } catch (IOException e) {

                throw new Error("Error copying database");

            }
        }

    }

    /**
     * Check if the database already exist to avoid re-copying the file each time you open the application.
     * @return true if it exists, false if it doesnt
     */
    private boolean checkDataBase(){

        SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

        try{
            String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
            checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);

        }catch(SQLiteException e){

            //database doest exist yet.

        }

        if(checkDB != null){

            checkDB.close();

        }

        return checkDB != null ? true : false;
    }

    /**
     * Copies your database from your local assets-folder to the just created empty database in the
     * system folder, from where it can be accessed and handled.
     * This is done by transfering bytestream.
     * */
    private void copyDataBase() throws IOException{



        //Open your local db as the input stream
        InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

        Log.d(TAG, "found the database");
        // Path to the just created empty db
        String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;


        //Open the empty db as the output stream
        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);


        //transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
        byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
        int length;
        while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }

        //Close the streams
        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
        myInput.close();

    }

    public void openDataBase() throws SQLException{

        //Open the database
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void close() {

            if(myDataBase != null)
                myDataBase.close();

            super.close();

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }

        // Add your public helper methods to access and get content from the database.
       // You could return cursors by doing "return myDataBase.query(....)" so itd be easy
       // to you to create adapters for your views.
```

Comment: I do not want to create this database at run time, which is what all the tutorials i have found are doing. I want them to be pulled offline so I can update and manage this database. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: If you want a database that is preloaded with the app, put it in your assets folder. I will update my post with some code to show you how.

Comment: I can do that at first, but when I expand this, I plan for it to be for college campuses, meaning a lot of files - and if I update the database, i do not want to have to push an update for the app.. is there a way to store the database online, and the app pull it off and read from it?

Comment: Yes. Your need to have a server with the database, and when the app loads, check for updates to the database. If there are updates have the server send the updates as a json or something, then put the results in your local database.

Comment: @coder have you ever had android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDiskIOException: disk I/O error using this code?  I got this on the getReadableDatabase().  I have asked the question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9808282/sqlitediskioexception-disk-i-o-error-when-creating-database

Answer (score 0):

A SQLite database would be an excellent way to accomplish your application goals. Based on what you said, a single table called "Restaurants" containing 5 fields: _id, Name, Address, Phone, Rank would do the trick.

The SQLite SQL documentation is located here: http://www.sqlite.org/lang.html . Some of the commands you'll need to be familiar with are CREATE TABLE, INSERT, UPDATE and SELECT. Sqlite for Android is a well-documented standard found across the web. You should have no trouble finding examples of how to accomplish your task.

Remember to close any database objects that you create else, you'll create a leak.

Good luck!

Comment: I do not want to create this database at run time, which is what all the tutorials i have found are doing. I want them to be pulled offline so I can update and manage this database. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: @comead If I understand correctly, you are looking for your android app to access an external database, pull restaurant data from it, and display it to the user? If this is true, will you want the user to have the ability to update the data, or will it be read only? It would be possible to use a web service to pull data from a database and parse it to a web service that serves up the restaurant data in JSON format. I won't go into any more details until you've confirmed that I do, in fact, understand your application objectives.

Comment: Yes, It would be read only. The reason i see it being an external database is because I want to be able to update/ manage the data within the database WITHOUT having to update the app itself. Another reason for it is because if this works out and spreads, I would need different databases for different college towns - and that just seems like a lot of files.

Comment: @comead SQLite just functions as the *local* database. Any synchronization is a different step :)

Comment: @pst well... how would you go about doing that? haha

Comment: @comead Search, mull it over, and then ask another focused SO question, as appropriate. Make sure you have the requirements ironed out.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is create a Web Service, this lives in the "cloud" on the Internets somewhere. Then you have your mobile app periodically contact the web service and request restaurant data perhaps based on the users current location, so the app passes the gps coordinates to the web service and the Web Service checks its database for restaurants within X distance of that location, then the Web Service returns the list to the app in a format such as Json or XML, the App parses this info and displays it to the user.

Ideally you would also have a database on the phone that would store results on the device this reduces the amount of requests you have to pull from the server, saving on battery, data and server resources. This gets a little complicated as you have to decide what to ask for intelligently and the server has to decide what to send you.

There was a Google I/O talk on how to do this.
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xHXn3Kg2IQE