# SQLiteDiskIOException caused by openOrCreateDatabase

Tags: android

I received this crash report in my Developer Console:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{ZhuangDictActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDiskIOException: disk I/O error
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1651)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3691)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:907)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:665)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDiskIOException: disk I/O error
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.native_setLocale(Native Method)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.setLocale(SQLiteDatabase.java:2144)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.<init>(SQLiteDatabase.java:1996)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:905)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:995)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:988)
at DatabaseHelper.initDb(DatabaseHelper.java:79)
at ZhuangDictActivity.onCreate(ZhuangDictActivity.java:329)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
... 11 more
```

This is part of DabaseHelper.java that is causing the problem:

```
public void initDb() {
    if (db != null) {
        db.close();
    }
    db = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(ZhuangDictActivity.dbFile, null);
}
```

The line 79 is db = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(ZhuangDictActivity.dbFile, null)
The part of ZhuangDictActiviy.java that is causing the problem:

```
if (dictName == null) {
} else {
    modifyDictVar(dictName);
    setTitle(loadDictInfo());

    initDbFile();
    databaseHelper.initDb();
}
```

The line 329 is databaseHelper.initDb()
Another part of ZhuangDictActivity.java that throw the IOException, I think:

```
private void initDbFile() {
    dbFile = new File(dbFileName);
    if (!dbFile.exists()) {
        try {
            dbFile.createNewFile();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            showErrorDialog(getString(R.string.error));
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

My project is involving writing the database to external storage. How should I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
dbFile = Environment.getDataDirectory() + “/data/YOUR_PACKAGE/databases/”;
```

also, take a look at the [similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9808282/sqlitediskioexception-disk-i-o-error-when-creating-database).

Comment: But my database is saved on external storage instead of internal.

Comment: I know. You can try internal db first to verify whether it is your code problem or system permission problem.

Comment: I tried to put the db into asset to be copied to external storage. So actually it is not necessary to create the database. How I should change the db = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(ZhuangDictActivity.dbFile, null) so that it will just try to open db? Is db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(ZhuangDictActivity.dbFile, null) acceptable?

Comment: [Equivalent to openDatabase(file.getPath(), factory, CREATE_IF_NECESSARY).](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html)