# What is the best approach for storing persistent information in android app

Tags: android

I am a beginner on android development. I want to save user details on android device. my application has a registration facility. I want to restrict only one user per device. If the user uninstalled the application and reinstalled it should take the previous user already registered with this device until the device is formatted. So for this purpose I want to store the user details inside the device and the user should not be able to clear the details until the device is formatted.

I am searching for solution something similar to iOS keychain concept, but it is not mandatory to save as encrypted.

Requesting experts help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create Android Database application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8525787/how-to-create-android-database-application)

Answer (score 0):

The better approach would be not to store that information on the user's device. You can store the details of the user on your server, and make use of the various device identifiers to determine if the user exists.

For example, you can use instanceID (which identifies unique app installations), along with IMEI (burned onto the hardware) to determine if it's the user's first install.

More info:
https://developer.android.com/training/articles/user-data-ids.html